# $.get() not working Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm tryin to get a value in URL from php file via $.get(), here is the code:

PHP folder called 'jquery_con4.php':

```
echo (isset($_GET['req'])) ? 'found':'notfound';
```

JQuery called 'pass.js':

```
$.get('connection/jquery_con4.php', function(data){
        alert(data);
});
```

the main folder called 'password_c.php' which include the javascript called 'pass.js' which has $.get but it shows me in note 'notfound', & if remove if echo, it shows be 'undefined index:req'
--- URL is: 'http://localhost/series/skyface/password_c.php?req=65yDq0zI39UcRSF'

Thanks!

Comment: How is that sending `req` data? Look at the manual, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/.

Comment: You don't have a `req` param in your url - ie. `$.get('connection/jquery_con4.php?req=true', function(data){`

Comment: i have req in url http://localhost/series/skyface/password_c.php?req=65yDq0zI39UcRSF

Comment: is your php code in `localhost/series/skyface/password_c.php?req=65yDq0zI39UcRSF` or `connection/jquery_con4.php`? if it is in `connection/jquery_con4.php`, then the `req` in  `localhost/series/skyface/password_c.php?req=65yDq0zI39UcRSF` does not automatically get sent, unless you add it to your `$.get()`

Comment: i have a file called connection in a folder called 'skyface', the password_c.php in skyface folder & jquery_con4,php in a file skyface/connection

Comment: I don't follow your last comment. Which file contains the php code you posted? `localhost/series/skyface/password_c.php?req=65yDq0zI39UcRSF` or `connection/jquery_con4.php`?

Comment: this localhost/series/skyface/password_c.php?req=65yDq0zI39UcRSF

Comment: it's not about the location cuz alert shows me 'notfound' which the problem isn't in location

Comment: it is about the location. If you are getting alert `notfound`, then that means `$_GET['req']` is not set. Based off your code, I would assume that your jquery `$.get()` is in `localhost/series/skyface/password_c.php?req=65yDq0zI39UcRSF` and your php code is in `connection/jquery_con4.php`. And since you did not add a `req` param to your `$.get()` call to `connection/jquery_con4.php`, you will always get  a `notfound` alert.

Comment: Very simple to inspect the actual request in broser dev tools network and see that the url has no params

Comment: simply -- i have folder called skyface --- which have folders called 'script' & 'connection' -- the skyface has **password_c.php** on root -- **jquery_con4.php** in connection folder -- JS in script folder which have $.get()....what will be wrong?

Comment: I understand your folder and file layout. But the question is which file is your code in? which file contains the php code and which file contains the javascript code?

Comment: looking at your comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642604/get-not-working-jquery#comment51232224_31642604. If your php code is in `localhost/series/skyface/password_c.php?req=65yDq0zI39UcRSF`, then your php code should alert `found`. But then that begs the question, why are you showing js code that does a `$.get()` to `connection/jquery_con4.php`?

Comment: the hole code which contain HTML & PHP  in file called **password_c.php** & javascripy in file called **pass.js** in scripts folder & i make new file called **jquery_con4.php** in folder connection now we have 3 files which i access in main file **password_c.php**

Comment: i want to get the value from URL by **jquery_con4.php** and pass it to **pass.js**

Comment: thanks i found the solution

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:8888/series/skyface/password_c.php?req=65yDq0zI39UcRSF

In order to pass the 'req' value from the URL querystring to the jquery_con4.php script, you need a JS function that will grab it for you and pass it into an ajax request.

Below is an example of how that might work.

/series/skyface/password_c.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

/main.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }

  function success(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }


  $.ajax({
    url: '/connection/jquery_con4.php',
    data: {req : getParameterByName('req')},
    success: success
  });

});
```

/connection/jquery_con4.php:

```
<?php echo(isset($_GET['req'])) ? 'found' : 'notfound'; ?>
```